# odd rake behavior - is it broken?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, tdd, rake

EDIT: figured it out. This is telling me my ruby is producing an infinite loop. Now if I could only figure out how to fix the loop ...

I run a rake test and this is all that outputs to the terminal:

```
(in /home/macs/Desktop/projects/odin/odin3_ruby/learn_ruby)

#translate
```

The test was working fine before I changed my ruby to this:

```
def translate(x)
    vowel = /\b[aeiou]*/
    array = x.split("")

    until array[0]==vowel do
        it = array[0]
        array.push(it)
        array.delete(it)
    end
    new = array.join("")    
    new+="ay"
end
```

I don't remember exactly what my ruby code was before I changed it.

If you are curious to see my rake file it is this. By the way I downloaded this file from the tutorial website and I am positive I didn't change it at all.

```
# # Topics
#
# * modules
# * strings
#
# # Pig Latin
#
# Pig Latin is a made-up children's language that's intended to be confusing. It obeys a few simple rules (below) but when it's spoken quickly it's really difficult for non-children (and non-native speakers) to understand.
#
# Rule 1: If a word begins with a vowel sound, add an "ay" sound to the end of the word.
#
# Rule 2: If a word begins with a consonant sound, move it to the end of the word, and then add an "ay" sound to the end of the word.
#
# (There are a few more rules for edge cases, and there are regional variants too, but that should be enough to understand the tests.)
#
# See <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_latin> for more details.
#
#

require "pig_latin"

describe "#translate" do

  it "translates a word beginning with a vowel" do
    s = translate("apple")
    s.should == "appleay"
  end

  it "translates a word beginning with a consonant" do
    s = translate("banana")
    s.should == "ananabay"
  end

  it "translates a word beginning with two consonants" do
    s = translate("cherry")
    s.should == "errychay"
  end

  it "translates two words" do
    s = translate("eat pie")
    s.should == "eatay iepay"
  end

  it "translates a word beginning with three consonants" do
    translate("three").should == "eethray"
  end

  it "counts 'sch' as a single phoneme" do
    s = translate("school")
    s.should == "oolschay"
  end

  it "counts 'qu' as a single phoneme" do
    s = translate("quiet")
    s.should == "ietquay"
  end

  it "counts 'qu' as a consonant even when it's preceded by a consonant" do
    s = translate("square")
    s.should == "aresquay"
  end

  it "translates many words" do
    s = translate("the quick brown fox")
    s.should == "ethay ickquay ownbray oxfay"
  end

  # Test-driving bonus:
  # * write a test asserting that capitalized words are still capitalized (but with a different initial capital letter, of course)
  # * retain the punctuation from the original phrase

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of Strings:

```
array = x.split("")
```

but you're comparing those strings with a Regexp:

```
vowel = /\b[aeiou]*/
#...
until array[0]==vowel do
```

`a == b` is false for every String `a` and Regexp `b` so you're just writing this in a complicated way:

```
until false do
```

Perhaps you mean to say:

```
until array[0] =~ vowel do
```

That should stop your infinite loop but your loop still doesn't make much sense. You do this:

```
it = array[0]
array.push(it)
array.delete(it)
```

So you grab the first element, [`push`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-push) it onto the end of the array, and then [`delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-delete) everything from `array` that matches `it` (note that `Array#delete` deletes *all* matches). Why not just `array.delete(it)`? Or, if you only want to toss the first entry, use [`shift`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-shift).

Comment: thanks, i ended up getting it working on my own. Still, you're advice is helpful. I realized I could use the slice method instead.